# How to edit all the data in an entire column?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In my MySQL database, I have a lot of data with the timestamp in this format:

```
2017.07.13 - 12:00:00:000
```

I want to change it to be in this format:

```
2017-07-13T12:00:00:000-0400
```

I know I need **SELECT** to get the data from the table and **UPDATE** to change it to a new record. But I don't know how to edit the timestamp using SQL commands.

**How can I edit a string using SQL commands?**

Comment: `UPDATE tablename set time='2017-07-13T12:00:00:000-0400' WHERE time='2017.07.13 - 12:00:00:000'`

Comment: Why are you storing timestamps as strings?

Comment: Did you consult the documentation for string modification functions? Which ones did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work (tested in SQL-Server)

```
Update tableName SET col = Replace(col," - ","T") + '-0400'
```

If `+` is not work for mysql then try CONCAT

Update: Solution for MySQL is

```
UPDATE tableName SET col = CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, ' - ', 'T'), '.', '-'), '-0400')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run a `select` prior to an `update`. The `update` has the data already available. You could do something like this:

```
update table 
set column = concat(replace(replace(column, ' - ', 'T'), '.', '-'), '-0400')
```

to alter the format of your all dates in the `column` column of the `table` table.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2699e9/2 (using select because the `update` wouldnt show anything)

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace
3. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

If you only want to update 1 specific row use a `where` clause to limit the `update` affects.